# How to fix Add Plugin Error with Word Press on IIS?

Tags: wordpress, windows, server

I´m using Windows Server 2012R2 with an IIS Webserver. When I want to add a Plugin in Word Press I am receiving this error:
*Installation failed: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.*

Note: Firewall is already disabled

[Health Check Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX2vn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Correct File and Folder Permissions in WordPress

```
755 for all folders and sub-folders
644 for all files
```

Here is one of article where you can find-out details to set permission from IIS

https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20760/How-to-Fix-a-Common-WordPress-Update-Error-in-IIS.html

Comment: I have followed the steps in the the article and have still the same problem